# What happens to the permalink that use %postname% if I change the post name

Tags: permalinks, seo

In my permalink i use only postname 
What will happen to the links if the post name changes? Will it still work ?
Otherwise what is the best practice?

With love

Comment: Do you mean links on your own site, or inbound links from elsewhere?

Comment: I mean the inbound links

Answer (score 1):

After the page is published WordPress creates a URL link based on your permalink settings. If you then change the post name the url link would not change automatically, although you can manually change it in the post.

Comment: Ok. What happens if I change that url settings (slug). What happens to the e external inbound links ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If an external inbound link is not working anymore because you changed the url of the post, you could use a redirect in your .htaccess or a plugin that handles redirects to get that inbound link to resolve. There may be some other plugin solutions to avoid 404 pages, but not in the basic WordPress installation.

Comment: What about using url like this. Www.site.com/?p=123/postname

Comment: Doesn´t look very nice. Either don´t change permalinks or use a plugin to check for broken permalinks.